# How do I create email alert when someone tries to use "sudo su"?

Tags: xubuntu

From:   test@abc.com
To: root@abc.com,
Date:   11.04.2014 04:33
Subject: SECURITY information for server1

```
server1 : Apr 11 10:33:19 : test : user NOT in sudoers ; TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/test ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/su -
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use `rsyslog` as logging daemon. Save the following 
configuration snippet as `/etc/rsyslog.d/60-sudo-mails.conf`.

```
# Load Mail output module
module(load="ommail")

# Template for the "Subject:" line to dynamically set the affected hostname 
template(
    name   = "mailSubject" 
    type   = "string" 
    string = "SECURITY information for %hostname%"
)

# If messages go to facility "authpriv" and have severity "warning" (or worse)
# and the program's name is "sudo", then perform the given action:
if ( prifilt("authpriv.warning") and ($programname == "sudo") ) then {

    action(
        type             = "ommail" 
        server           = "your_mail_server_here, e.g. mail.abc.com"
        port             = "25"
        mailfrom         = "test@abc.com"
        mailto           = "root@abc.com"
        body.enable      = "on"
        subject.template = "mailSubject"
    )

}
```

Make sure you configure a mail server that allows to send emails without
authentication. Usually this will be a mailserver in your local network
but **not** GMail or something like that because `rsyslog`'s output module
[`ommail`](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/ommail.html) can currently not be configured for authentication 
(username/password). You may also want to add the parameter

```
action.execOnlyOnceEveryInterval = "600"
```

to the action so you get only *one* email every 10 minutes (the others are
simply discarded). It depends on how often you expect such a message.

When done, restart `rsyslog`:

```
sudo systemctl restart rsyslog.service
```

Try out by either issueing a prohibited `sudo` command or by running

```
logger -p authpriv.warning -t sudo "This should be sent as an email"
```

The above configuration will put the logmessage *"as is"* into the mail body.
If you prefer some formatting or different appearance then you need to supply
a [`template`](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/ommail.html#template) for the email's body