# Be notified (e.g. mail) of unsuccessful FTP login attempts to my server

Tags: email, ftp

I have a server I log in to with FTP. I'd like to know of a way to be notified of fraudulent login attempts.

Comment: Confusing - "login fails .... if anyone logs in". If the login failed, nobody got logged in.

Comment: actually if we have correct credentials then there is no problem. If login to FTP server fails i need an email alert or echo statement i.e "login failed"

Comment: its FTP not ssh

Comment: you guys are really not nice, this is a new user, quit downvoting

Comment: @tatsu Downvote means a “question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful”. Thank you for improving the question, I bet it gets no more downvotes now.

Comment: What about letting `rsyslog` send an email when the `ftpd` writes certain logmessages? As in [this similar post](https://askubuntu.com/q/1098647/504066)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST='IP_address'
USER='USER_NAME'
PASSWD='Pa$$word'

OUT="$(ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT 
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
put /test.txt
quit
END_SCRIPT
)"

if [ -z "$OUT" ]; then
    echo "Uploaded successfully"
else
    echo "Uploading failed"
fi
echo $OUT

exit 0
```

Hi,
MR.venkat try to add send commands in if else block to send mail. Hope this code helps you out.

Comment: tq sir, its working

Comment: unsuccessful login attempts will also be notified by printing uploading file is failed. we should change the code according to our requirement in if else block. Thank you.

Comment: Why would you log unsuccessful login attempts _on the client_? That code won't help when an attacker tries to access the OP's ftp server from his (the attacker's) PC. You need to look at the ftp _server's logfiles_ to detect malicious login attempts, not at the client.

Answer (score 1):

Install **fail2ban** in order to ban and send emails

here is how you can install this software :

1. Open up a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>)
2. type : `sudo apt install fail2ban sendmail` (being on an updated system is of importance)
3. then allow SSH access through UFW and then enable the firewall:

   `ufw allow ssh
    ufw enable`

the default configuration should be adequate all that is left to do is configure your mail

source : https://www.linode.com/docs/security/using-fail2ban-for-security/#ubuntu

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! This answer would be useful if you were to go into more detail on how to configure `fail2ban` after installation in order to accomplish the desired goal. Hint: You can find this information [here.](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8) I highkly recommend that you review https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer Cheers!